# problems with creating an NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I am new to Cocoa, and I am just experimenting with creating a window programmatically (without using Interface Builder).

I start a new Cocoa Application in Xcode, then I remove the window from the nib file in Interface Builder to replace it with my own one.

In the main function, I add the code:

```
NSWindow* myWindow; 

myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(10,100,400,300)
  styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
  backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
  defer:NO];
```

When I try to build and run the application, I receive the following error message:

> Error (1002) creating CGSWindow

Why does this happen??? What is a CGSWindow by the way?

Rainer

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have a connection to the window server yet. That's NSApplication's job, so try creating the [shared application](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSApplication/sharedApplication) first.

If that doesn't help, I'd just go through with my usual application layout: Create an NSObject subclass for a custom controller, instantiate this from your application delegate's `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` and release it in `applicationWillTerminate:`, and have your custom controller's `init` method create the window. The application object will definitely be running by this point (as `main` does nothing but call `NSApplicationMain`, which gets/creates the shared application and tells it to run), so you should definitely have your connection to the window server and so be able to create the window.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code you've written into the following method from your App Delegate implementation file -

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
 // Insert code here to initialize your application 

 NSWindow* myWindow; 

 myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(10,100,400,300)
             styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
              defer:NO];
}
```

and it should load your window perfectly.

It's worth noting that it's never safe and is not a good practice to create any UI related objects in your `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a completely empty window from scratch this is all the code you'll need:

```
//if you used a template this will be already in the file:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];
    int retval=UIApplicationMain(argc,argv,nil,@"SimpleWindowAppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}

@implementation SimpleWindowAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIWindow *window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIDevice mainScreen] bounds]];
    //You could create views and add them here:
    //UIView *myView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrane:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
    //[window addSubView:myView];
    //[myView release];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
@end
```

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about NSWindow; why are you providing an iOS example?Also, `NSApplicationMain()` - unlike `UIApplicationMain()`, doesn't let you pass in your own principal class & app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The only code that you will probably ever want to have in your main() function in a Cocoa application is automatically created for you by XCode (if you are using it).

I suggest that you add the code that you want into your applicationDelegate's -applicationDidFinishLaunching: method

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(10,100,400,300)
        styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
        defer:NO];;
}
```